# can only select a ONE radio repeater

Tags: angularjs

It is such that I have a repeater, which has two radios, the two must select only one of them.

If you click on one, then the other will be disabled and vice versa if it should be that way.

So if it is so must be True A and B must be False. so there will only ever be a departure.

index.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="pric in UserPrice">
     <div ng-class="{'PopAddNow': pric.Mdr < 6, 'PopAddNow': pric.Mdr >= 6}" class="padding" style="padding:2px 3px;">
     <input type="radio" value="{{pric.Prics}}" ng-model="Pakke1" />
          Members - {{pric.Mdr}} months {{pric.Prics}}
     </div>
</div>
```

What the problem is right now, it's such a and b can be true together. it may be they do not, you have to choose only one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per standard HTML, make sure the radio buttons have the same value for the `name` attribute. E.g.:

```
<input name="pakke1" type="radio" value="{{pric.Prics}}" ng-model="Pakke1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for fast help. I will confirm your reply as soon as I can do it. I hope you will give me a question like or +1